# what is meant by perspective function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

the perspective function $P : \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to  \mathbb{R}^n$, with domain dom $P = \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^{++}$, as $P(z,t) = \frac{z}t$. (Here $\mathbb{R}^{++}$ denotes the set of positive numbers: $\mathbb{R}^{++} = \{x \in \mathbb{R} | x > 0\}$.) The perspective function scales or normalizes vectors so the last component is one, and then drops the last component.

I was reading convex optimisation and I am not able to understand what is a perspective function !  can any one explain please

Comment: Think of it as perpsective projection onto the hyperplane consisting of points with last coordinate equal to $1$. It maps all points along a line through the origin (minus the origin itself) onto the point of intersection of this line with the hyperplane.

Comment: can u please elaborate the point (It maps all points along a line through the origin (minus the origin itself) onto the point of intersection of this line with the hyperplane.) ?

Comment: The parameterization $t(z,1)$ for some fixed $z$ describes a line through the origin. $P$ maps every point on this line to $z$. Try a few examples in $\mathbb R^3$ to visualize what’s going on.

Comment: A related topic is the simple pinhole camera model that's used in computer graphics and computer vision. Perspective projection is a special case where the eye of the camera is at the origin and the camera is looking along the the last coordinate axis.

Answer (score 2):

The perspective function $P:R^{n+1} \to R^n$ is defined mathematically as:

$P(x,t) = x/t, \ \ \ domain\ of\ P = \{ (x,t) | t>0\}$

Intuitively it can be explained as Professor Stephen Boyd explains,
"Divide first $n$ elements of the vector by its last component".

Comment: I do not see the quoted statement “divide first....... components” in the Convex Optimization book of Boyd. It is incorrect too.

Comment: I think he means think $(x,t)$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $t >0$ as $(y)$ where $y \in \mathbb{R^{n+1}}$. Now, the perspective is $P(y) = y_{n+1} f(y_{1:n}/y_{n+1})$. But this answer has issues.

Comment: The above comment by @SJa is actually correct. Think of $(x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$. Then, the perspective function take such a vector, divide all its components by its $(n+1)$-th coordinate, makes the last coordinate 1 and then discards it.

Answer (score 1):

For any fixed $z$, $P$ maps all points of the form $t(z,1)$, $(t>0)$ to $z$. These points form a ray emanating from the origin, so you can think of $P$ as the perspective projection onto the the hyperplane that consists of all points with last coordinate equal to $1$. The image of a point in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ is then the point of intersection of the ray through the point and this hyperplane.